# php include/require с параметрами

Tags: php

Есть html разметка страницы (её шапка):

```html
<header class="header container">
    <nav class="navigation">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">О нас</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="news.php">Новости</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="management.php">Управление</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="documents.php">Документы</a>
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-active" href="community.php">Сообщество</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="contacts.php">Контакты</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

На каждой странице (о нас, новости и т.д.) меняются стили в навигации, в зависимости от того, где находится пользователь с помощью класса .nav-link-active. Например, если пользователь на странице "новости", то ссылка на новости будет иметь такой формат:

```html
<a class="nav-link nav-link-active" href="news.php">Новости</a>
```

**Вопрос:**

Как мне сделать так, чтобы эту шапку можно было вынести в отдельный файл и с помощью include/require с параметрами или как-то по-другому менять класс в зависимости от станицы?

Comment: почитайте про шаблонизаторы какие нить а-ля twig/smarty

Comment: тупо определить все нужные переменные перед вызовом include

Comment: если говорить про вывод меню - а это ДРУГОЙ вопрос (и непонятно, почему именно он не был задан) - то я бы сделал массив вида `['about.php' => 'О нас', ...]`, выводил его в цикле, и внутри цикла сравнивал ключ с `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`

Comment: @Ипатьев, спасибо, помогли